# Скрипт валидатора

Tags: javascript, html

Есть select

```
<select id="hidid[7]" name="idvis[7]" onchange="Javascript:ChangePrice(7,this.value);">
<option value="8:+0">выбрать    </option>
<option value="82:+0">120x60   </option>
<option value="83:+240">125x65   (+240 руб.)</option>
<option value="73:+1840">200x90   (+1840 руб.)</option>
</select>
```

Подскажите javascript код, который работал бы по onclick. Хотелось бы, если не выбрано ничего, то он работал бы по принципу

```
document.getElementById('IDблока').style.display='block'
```

Чтобы в этом id я запихнул текст "выберете то-то и это",  т.е сменил стиль дива с `display:none;` на `display:block;`

И можно ли как-то валидатор не привязывать к `<form action=''>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Если я правильно понял, то:

   ```
   var sel = document.getElementById('hidid[7]');
   if( !sel.value )
   {
     /* действия для "ничего не выбрано" */
     return false;
   }
   ```
2. Повесить валидатор можно на что угодно, хоть на клик по произвольному месту, или на проводку мышой над определённой точкой :) При прохождении валидации:

   ```
   var frm = document.getElementById('form_id');
   frm.submit();
   ```

Comment: а как обратиться к первому варианту?

Comment: <script>
var sel = document.getElementById('{/literal}hidid[{$options_data.ID}]{literal}');
if( !sel.value ){
function opt()
{
  document.getElementById('nooptions').style.display='block';
  return false;
}}
</script>

onclick="javascript: opt()"
Сделал. спасибо